# Users cannot log in, what is wrong?

Tags: php, authentication

Okay I have tried to make a login system with users. But my users cannot log in. And well that is a problem.

My login page:

```
<?
session_start();

include "database.php";
?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Wildsoul</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="welcome">
        <h3>Log ind.</h3>
<br><br>
        <p><form action="login-ok.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username"><br>
<input type="password" name="password"><br><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
</form></p>




                                <br /><br />

    </div>
                    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The login-ok page:

```
<?
session_start();

include "database.php";
?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
        <div id="welcome">
        <h3>Log in</h3>
        <p><?php // PHP script start.
require("config.php"); // Variabler til mysql hentes
$login = &$HTTP_POST_VARS['login'];
$_SESSION['login'] = $login; //AF rettelse

if(empty($login)) {
    echo 'You need to log in'; }
    else {

$username = &$HTTP_POST_VARS['username']; // Brugernavn fra form i login.php.
$password = &$HTTP_POST_VARS['password']; // Password fra form i login.php.

if(empty($username) OR empty($password)) { //Her tjekkes om ET af felterne er tomme.
    echo 'Et af felterne er tomme'; }   
    else { // Denne klamme starter alt script der udføres HVIS begge felter er udfyldte.

// Her åbnes for mysql-serveren og der logges ind med data fra config.php.
mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pw);
mysql_select_db($mysql_db); // Der åbnes for databasen defineret i config.php.


 $result_pw = mysql_query("select password from users where brugernavn = '$username'") or die (mysql_error()); 
$result_user = mysql_query("select brugernavn from users where password = '$password'") or die (mysql_error()); 


// Her sker det egentlige tjek om brugernavn og password er dem som står i databasen.
// Der oprettes først et array med de data vi fik fra mysql før.
$array_user = mysql_fetch_array($result_user); // Først et med brugernavn.
$array_pw = mysql_fetch_array($result_pw); // Og et med password.
// Her tjeckes så om både array med brugernavn og password indeholder data
// magen til dem skrevet i felterne i html-formen
// PASSWORD KONTROL
if($array_user['username'] == $username AND $array_pw['password'] == $password) {
  echo 'correct password. <a href="http://wildsoul.dk/indeks.php">Klik her</a>.'; // Brugernavn og password passede!!
$_SESSION['username'] = $username; //AF rettelse
$_SESSION['password'] = $password; //AF rettelse 

} // Her lukker vi condition TRUE fra password kontrol

else { // Her starter condition FALSE på password kontrol
echo 'forkert password';
} // Her lukkes condition FALSE på password kontrol.

} // Her lukker vi for condition FALSE på tomme-felter-tjek.
}
?>
</p>


                                <br /><br />

    </div>
                    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And when I have to check if the user has logged in, I have this code:

```
<?
session_start();

include "database.php";
?>

<? if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])){ ?>

bla bla bla

<?}
else{
echo 'You have to log in'; }
?>
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: just a heads up from a quick overview of the code posted: $HTTP_POST_VARS is deprecated, use $_POST instead

Comment: What message do your users get when they try to login? Also its probably not safe to store username and password in $_SESSION. A better option is to create a unique session id for their visit and use that to verify that the session is valid. Session id can be tied to the visitors IP address for instance to ensure that the session is not hijacked by someone else.

Comment: and... as a follow-up, <? is deprecated as well. Then, you will get serious SQL injection problems if you do not escape your inputs. Finally, assignment by reference is unneeded as well.

Comment: Well I have changed <? to <?php and changed $HTTP_POST_VARS to $_POST, removed the if(empty($login)) and deleted the space before first <? . But it still doesn't work !!! :/ 

but there is still problems. :/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a logic problem, you're checking $login before actually trying to validate the user. Remove that and just try validate them and then set your session variables.

So remove the if(empty($login)) ... and just connect to your db etc. If that doesn't work, try editing your post with what problems you're getting besides "it doesn't work" :)

Answer (score 0):

- You have spaces before first `<?` so session cannot be started successfully - it might be your whole problem
- Do not use short starting PHP tags `<?` but use `<?php`